# How to change the label color of an IntField - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I change the label color of an IntField in Unity?
I have tried the following:

```
TextFieldStyles = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.textField);
GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
GUI.color = Color.white;
TextFieldStyles.normal.textColor = Color.white;
EditorGUILayout.IntField(label,value,TextFieldStyles);
```

The only field that changes is the 'value' field. The 'label' field however, stays black. How can I change it to, for example, white?

'GUI.color' calls do nothing at all, possibly because it is an Editor Window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the color of a Label with `TextFieldStyles.normal.textColor` .

```
int value = 1;
string label = "User Name: ";
void OnGUI()
{
    GUIStyle TextFieldStyles = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.textField);
    GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
    GUI.color = Color.white;

    //Value Color
    TextFieldStyles.normal.textColor = Color.white;

    //Label Color
    EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.yellow;

    EditorGUILayout.IntField(label, value, TextFieldStyles);
}
```